# Show div after X% of body's height

Tags: jquery, if-statement, height

How can I invoke a div, to show it on top (a search bar and some functions), after 300px of page's heigh have been scrolled?

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user scrolls, at a certain point to show another div containing some tools.

Comment: do you mean you want your div not to move when the user scrolls the page?

Comment: no, I want to show a div on top after the user has scrolled X% or px of the body's height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that's what you're looking for:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#my-div').hide();
});
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 300) {
       $('#my-div').show(200);
    } else {
      $('#my-div').hide(200);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#my-div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
body {
  height: 11100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-div">
  Search: <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/welcome/49824

Comment: Can't figure it out mate, won't go.. does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/fMtMF/ The `if` I mean because the `else` goes for me

Comment: Yea, seems to be a firefox issue... any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Check out my example http://jsbin.com/welcome/49824, I've just tested it in Firefox and it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.scroll()` to fire an event, and use `.scrollTop()` to calculate the height scrolled from the top of the page.

Then depending on this value, show/hide the tools:

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
        if (document.body.scrollTop>300){
            $(".tools").show();
       } else
       {
           $(".tools").hide();
       }
    });
```

[**-- View Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUPxN/2)

Comment: well, for some reasons the if doesn't go mate... and neither in the demo. The else does it's job

Comment: @w0rldart Which browser? I've updated my demo to some raw JS (in case the jQuery was causing issues on your browser)

Comment: I'm using firefox, can't figure out why it ain't working. Let me know if this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fMtMF/

Comment: @w0rldart You scrolled down in the window in the bottom right? (I'm unsure how experienced you are with jsfiddle)

Comment: yea, I'm familiar with jsfiddle

Comment: Aha, so it's a firefox issue... on IE, Chrome, Safari works great.